# HTTP PUT Array of objects

Tags: node.js, angular, http, express

I'm trying to update a list of Objects on the MongoDB with just one method call (for inside the Submit), but it dosnt work.. I spend the whole day yesterday and couldnt make it work..
I have a product on the database, and i want to update all products with the sells (i have a form with all products and an input box with Sells, i fill all of them and click on Save).

Frontend: Angular
Backend: Node (with express)
Database: MongoDB (mLab.com)

productSells.component.html (Sells input):

```
    <input type="number" id="sells" class="form-control"
        formControlName="sells" value="{{ product.sells }}">
```

productSells.component.ts

```
    products: Product[] = [];
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createFormControls();
    this.createForm();
    this.productService.getProducts()
      .subscribe(products => {
        this.products = products;
      },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }    
     createFormControls() {
    this.sells = new FormControl(0, [
      Validators.required
    ]);
  }    
  createForm() {
    this.sellsForm = new FormGroup({
      sells: this.sells,
    });
  }
  sellsSubmit() {
    for (const prod of this.products) {
      const product = new Product(
        this.sells.value
      );
      this.router.navigate([`/products/sells/${prod._id}`]);
      this.productService.updateProduct(prod._id, product);
    }
    location.reload();
  }
```

Node:

```
iceRouter.route('/products/sells/:productId')
    .put((req, res) => {
        IceCream.findById(req.params.productId, (err, iceC) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            iceC.sells = req.body.sells;
            iceC.save();
            res.json(iceC);
        })
    })
```

product.service.ts - updateProduct():

```
    updateProduct(pId: string, product: Product): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.put<Product>(`${this._productUrl}/${pId}`, product, this.httpOptions);
}
```

If i use postman with the product _id i can update the sells, but not on the application..
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

@Edit - Added last version of the code :

productSells.component.html

```
<input name="sells{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="products[i].sells" 
    type="number" class="form-control" id="sells" 
    formControlName="sells" value="{{ product.sells }}">
```

productSells.component.ts

```
  sellsSubmit() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
      const product = new Product(
        this.products[i].sells
      );
      this.router.navigate([`/products/sells/${this.products[i]._id}`]);
      this.productService.updateProduct(this.products[i]._id, product).subscribe(() => {
        console.log('sellsSubmit done!');
      });
    }
    location.reload();
  }
```

Codes:

[ProductSells.component.html](https://snipsave.com/kauannagashi/#/snippet/gydqLqGonk19xyhDH0)

[ProductSells.component.ts](https://snipsave.com/kauannagashi/#/snippet/iNYOUHsCJiMmBOXJJ4)

[Product.service.ts](https://snipsave.com/kauannagashi/#/snippet/ukoyA3vnD77mDca4gp)

Comment: It looks like you are updating the data inside updateproduct method of ProductService class, can you post that code also.

Comment: Hello @AdrianFâciu, thank you for your suggestion. I just added the updateProduct from the product.service.ts on the main post.
I'm still trying to figure out why its not working, but without success :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the `http.put` call, otherwise the HTTP request isn't made:

```
this.productService.updateProduct(prod._id, product).subscribe(() => {
    // This callback is invoked once the HTTP call has returned 
    console.log("Done");
});
```

Comment: Hello @user184994, thank you for your reply.
After i use the subscribe, the method worked! Thank you!
But theres a problem.. All products are being updated with the same value (the last one), if i use sells 10, 20, 30, 40 in 4 different products respectively, all of them will end with Sells == 40 :/

Comment: It looks like your getting the value from `this.sells.value`, and there only seems to be 1 of `this.sells`, so it has no way of knowing all 4 values...

Comment: Well, i think i'm a moron..
Yeah, i was goind to comment that hahaha
How could i have "infinite" amount of sellsInput to get the value from? (since the list of products can be infinite)

Comment: The productSells.component.html have a ngFor to create the fields to show the productName ( {{ product.productName}} ) and the input with id="sells" from the main topic code

Comment: The simplest way would be to store the value against the product object I think

Comment: Hi @user184994, thank you again for your time!
I managed to solve the problem using ngModel= products[i].sells and to save instead of this.sells.value to this.products[i].sells.

Comment: @KauanNagashi Sounds perfect, glad you got it working

Comment: The problem now is: When i open the modal, it re-write all values with the last one, lets say the first product have sells 10 and the second sells 30, on the form it shows 30 - 30 (but on the Database the sells are all right) and throws an error : ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '10'. Current value: '30'

Comment: I will accept your answer since it helped me to fix the main topic problem :D

Comment: @KauanNagashi Can you update the code in your question then please and I'll take a look

Comment: Hello @user184994, first of all, REALLY thanks for your time, i'm really grateful for you help!
Sorry for the late response, i tried to remake the entire program, but it got worse :/
I updated the main post with the code. Thank you :D

Comment: I added the whole classes there (links at the end of the main post)